# Javascript invalid reference in nested functions call

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to avoid utilizing `self = this` because it's conflicting with one of my plugin?

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        self = this;
    }
      
    fetchURL(url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
           self.func1();
        });
     }

    func1() {
        console.log("func1");
        self.func2();
    }

    func2() {
        console.log("func2");
    }
}


document.getElementById("basicFetchButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    let test = new Test();
    test.fetchURL('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js')
    // Loading the jQuery code

});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="basicFetchButton" value="Try it">
```

Comment: Looks like self is a global variable here. Is this intended?

Comment: How is it interfering with a plugin? Because you’re using a global “self” instead of attaching it to the instance using “this” or using a different variable name? Or because you’re not using arrow functions to bind “this” automatically?

Comment: @DaveNewton that's the unknown mystery, all I know is the `self=this` breaks one of the date-picker.

Comment: @WiktorZychla what do you mean by a global variable? It's capsulated in a class.

Comment: @rj487 No it isn’t; it’s not “this.self” or declared in the constructor.

Comment: @DaveNewton I see your point, yes it's a global variable and how do I prevent it?

Comment: The duplicate has full details, but the short version is that you should remove the constructor, use `this` in place of `self`, and use `(response) => {` instead of `function (response) {` so that function doesn’t have its own separate `this` value.

Comment: Either use [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `.then(response => { this.func1(); });` or `bind` `this`: `.then(this.func1.bind(this));`, and then you can remove `self` altogether.

Comment: The arrow function helps. I am keeping this question since the other link doesn't have an example in class.

Comment: If someone answers it, I will pick it as the answer.